# Avoiding a line break at the beginning of an enumerate

Tags: lists, line-breaking, enumerate

How can I avoid the line break at the begin of an `enumerate` environment? I've noticed that theorem-style environments succeed in doing so. I'm using the `enumitem` package and my concrete example is:

```
\textbf{Example:} % don't want a line break here!
\begin{enumerate}
  \item test1
  \item test2
\end{enumerate}
```

I tried wrapping the `enumerate` in a `vbox` but that just shifted the entire list up...

Comment: What behavior do you want? You want **Example:** 1. test 1 and then on the next line 2. test2? Should the 1 and 2 be aligned?

Comment: @TH No, I only want to influence the first line. The rest of the list should be formated as usual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an attempt to imitate the theorem environments from the AMS classes:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myexample}
{\trivlist \item[\hskip\labelsep\textbf{Example:}]}
%  {\trivlist \item[]\setbox\@labels\hbox{\textbf{Example: }}}
  {\endtrivlist}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some
text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's
some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some
text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text.
\begin{myexample}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Test 1
  \item Test 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{myexample}
Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some
text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's
some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some
text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of the `\@labels` box trick here? Without an `\everypar` mechanism as in amsthm, it is equivalent to `\item[\hskip\labelsep\textbf{Example:}]`.

Comment: @Philippe Goutet: Yes, they seem equivalent; I was just being lazy and copying the mechanism used by list environments (which includes theorem environments).  This really does use `\everypar`, since that's how the box `\@labels` is put onto the page. list environments accumulate the labels from nested list environments into `\@labels`, and `\everypar` dumps that onto the page.

Comment: precisely. As `\item` takes care of stacking automatically, just as well use it. What I meant about amsthm is that goes further with `\everypar` trickery: when the theorem is not followed by a list, it unboxes the label in order to allow long theorem titles without going into the margin (as they would with a simple `\item[...]`).

Comment: @Jonathan, @Philippe Gautet: I just edited the answer to use the line suggested by Philippe; it's better that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can fool the first item label to typeset whatever you want. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\fixitem[1]{\item[]
  \refstepcounter{enumi}\hskip-\labelwidth\hskip-\labelsep
  #1 \labelenumi}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Example:} don't want a line break here, see below!

\begin{enumerate}
  \fixitem{\textbf{Example:}} test1
  \item test2
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The outcome is:

[image: result of TeX run]